# Playing HTML5 audio without stopping iTunes audio on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, html5-audio, trigger.io

I'm trying to play audio in the background, but as soon as I insert the `<audio>` element into the page, the background music on the iPhone stops. I'm wondering if there's a solution to this via HTML5, or if I'm going to have to go through native and build yet another plugin to play my audio and dim out the background audio.

Thanks!

Comment: We're working on a native audio playback API which may resolve this issue. I'll update here again when it's ready to try.

Comment: I too require this and have encouraged Trigger.IO folks to add it.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm also looking to implement functionality like Google Maps and RunKeeper that play audio messages over the background music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do it. Even with the Web Audio API in iOS 6, as soon as you begin playback of an audio buffer in the browser, iTunes is immediately paused.

Comment: How do Google Maps and RunKeeper do it?

Comment: @Garrett are those HTML apps? Native apps can play *sounds* alongside *music*. In the browser you can't (yet, as far as I know)